# gnuplot epslatex pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot

I'm trying to embed my plot created in gnuplot. Just setting the terminal to latex works fine but only creates a black and white plot. With the color screens getting cheaper these days this isn't quite satisfying :D

The manual also mentions the possibility to use epslatex, then converting the eps file to a pdf file and include the generated latex file completely messes up the spacing between the labels on the axis and the actual graph. This happens both times, when creating a latex file for inclusion and also when creating a standalone file.

Guessing that I'm not the only one I ask myself what I am doing wrong and weather there is an easy workaround.

[image: Messed up spacing]

Comment: `set terminal pdf` is accepted

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Include the plot file and the commands you run.

Comment: @egreg: This would likely deny the option to use the document's fonts (I can see that you can only pre-set one font for the `pdf` terminal) and also to include TeX macros in labels.

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov take any plot, set the terminal to epslatex standalone and run gnuplot. Convert the eps file to pdf using eps2pdf then run pdflatex on the tex file generated.

Comment: Interesting I don't have epstopdf

Comment: @Nils: With my previous comment I meant that `set terminal epslatex color; set output "plot.tex"` and `\input{plot}` in the main document worked for me. But now I tested the `standalone` option, and it still works here. I have gnuplot 4.4.

Comment: Yes I just saw that it is called epstopdf (and not eps2pdf for whatever reason) using this utility it worked. So it seems that using ps2pdf was the problem.

Comment: This is likely related, but still doesn't explain _why_ this happens: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17345/xetex-and-graphicx-characters-missing-in-eps

Comment: I guess post script includes a border or something, eps is called Encapsulated Post Script for some reason.

Comment: The developer version of gnuplot has a tikz terminal which would allow you to output tikz code. It also supports the standalone class. Worth a try, but I think it is still beta and you have to check if it works ok for your application

Answer (score 2):

There are several tools for EPS to PDF conversion: at least `ps2pdf`, `epspdf` and `epstopdf`. It can be verified that the first one of these (which uses GhostScript) creates a PDF of page size (say, A4 or US Letter) and not content size, while the other two work as expected. Some [internet](http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2007/06/bounding-boxes-and-eps-to-pdf.html) [digging](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=303107#10) shows that GhostScript accepts the `-dEPSCrop` option, which clips the picture to its bounding box.

So, use either of `epspdf`, `epstopdf` or `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` to properly convert the picture.